# sql get column value which all values in another column no value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table which contains 4 columns:

column A - must has value and allow duplicate
column B - may be empty
column C - may be empty
column D - must has unique value

**example**:

```
  A  |  B  |   C  |  D
  ---|-----|------|-------    
  a1 | b1  |   -  | 101  
  a1 | -   |  c1  | 102
  a1 | b2  |  -   | 103
  a2 | -   |  -   | 104 
  a2 | b3  |  -   | 105   
  a3 | b4  |  c2  | 106
  a3 | -   |  c3  | 107
  a3 | -   |  c4  | 108
```

What I want is get column A and column B value where for the value in column A, all records in column C no value.

In the example I want to get the following **result**:

```
 A    |    B 
------------- 
 a2   |
 a2   |    b3
```

Comment: WHERE A IS NOT NULL and C IS NULL

Comment: Hi jarlh, but there have same value in column A. I want all column C no value.

Comment: @juergend I believe that you would get the answer very quick if you explain what do you want more clearly

Comment: can you please elaborate your last sentence little bit more to give some light to the actual requirement..?

Comment: Hi all, I want a2 values only if no a2 row has a C value as mentioned in jarlh's answer, sorry for the unclear description. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you mean all a2 values because no a2 row has a C value?

```
select a, b
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.a = t2.a
                  and c is not null)
```

Comment: Hi jarlh, thanks. Yes your understanding is correct but I have only 1 table.

Comment: @MapleLi only 1 table is used

Comment: @MapleLi, yes, it's the same table in both main query and sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      A CHAR(2) ,
      B CHAR(2) ,
      C CHAR(2) ,
      D INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'a1', 'b1', NULL, 101 ),
        ( 'a1', NULL, 'c1', 102 ),
        ( 'a1', 'b2', NULL, 103 ),
        ( 'a2', NULL, NULL, 104 ),
        ( 'a2', 'b3', NULL, 105 ),
        ( 'a3', 'b4', 'c2', 106 ),
        ( 'a3', NULL, 'c3', 107 ),
        ( 'a3', NULL, 'c4', 108 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   t1.* ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.A ORDER BY t1.C ) AS R
               FROM     @t t1
                        JOIN @t t2 ON t2.A = t1.A
             )
    SELECT  t.A ,
            t.B
    FROM    cte
            JOIN @t t ON t.A = cte.A
    GROUP BY t.A ,
            t.B
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ( R )) = 1
```

Output:

```
A   B
a2  NULL
a2  b3
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi Nakeuri, awesome! It get the correct answer, . But how can I do the same from an existing table with thousands of record? Thank you!